# send notification to mobile and get feedback from user

Tags: php, sms-gateway

i am working on a project, there is concept i dont know how to deal with it.
I need to send notification to the user on their mobile device, to understand lets take an example :-

like i want to ask to my friend weather he wants to go for movie or not.
i need to send notification to his mobile device, the notification will be

" do you like to go for movie " -: then he will reply with yes or no, now this reply will store to the database.

this notification may be sms or something else, i dont know how to deal with it weather i need to use sms service or something else or some technology. i am working in php web technology.

Please share you idea.

thanks

Comment: Why would anyone do this when they could send a text on their own?

Answer (score 2):

[Twilio](http://twilio.com/) may be a good solution for what you're trying to do.

You can use the [PHP Helper](https://www.twilio.com/docs/php/install) library to interact with their REST API like so:

```
<?php

require "/path/to/twilio-php/Services/Twilio.php";

// set your AccountSid and AuthToken from www.twilio.com/user/account
$AccountSid = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$AuthToken = "YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY";

$client = new Services_Twilio($AccountSid, $AuthToken);

$sms = $client->account->sms_messages->create(
    "YYY-YYY-YYYY", // From this number
    "XXX-XXX-XXXX", // To this number
    "Test message!"
);

// Display a confirmation message on the screen
echo "Sent message {$sms->sid}";
```

Then you can capture a text message using [this example](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/sms/replying-to-sms-messages):

```
<?php

    // make an associative array of senders we know, indexed by phone number
    $people = array(
        "+14158675309"=>"Curious George",
        "+14158675310"=>"Boots",
        "+14158675311"=>"Virgil",
    );

    // if the sender is known, then greet them by name
    // otherwise, consider them just another monkey
    if(!$name = $people[$_REQUEST['From']]) {
        $name = "Monkey";
    }

    // now greet the sender
    header("content-type: text/xml");
    echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";
?>
<Response>
    <Message><?php echo $name ?>, thanks for the message!</Message>
</Response>
```

Good luck!

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer. If you provided an example with how to use the service, that would be fine. Just pointing a person to a service, is a comment.

Comment: @JustinWood pointed to the PHP Helper library for Twilio and posted the example code found on their docs. To be honest, OP could've found all of this with some quick Googling anyways so the question isn't really SO-worthy, not to mention the question could be perceived as broad since there's many SMS gateway providers out there and the "best one" could become a subjective or opinionated answer